# Excel VBA "Appliction-defined or object-defined error"

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to clculate a formula that takes number from Column D and calcultes this number minus 14 in column C. 
Then, I'm triyng to autofill the range down to the first cell I calculate.

at first it was working, but now it shows me an error:

> appliction-defined or object-defined error

to this line of code

```
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=ActiveCell.Range("A1:A" & lastrow)
```

If someone would help me to solve this prblem I'll be glad.

```
OP_wb.Sheets("Optic Main").Activate

Dim FirstRow As Range
Dim lastrow As Range


Set FirstRow = Range("C1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)
Set lastrow = Range("E1").End(xlDown).Offset(0, -2)

Range("E1").End(xlDown).Offset(0, -2).Select

            Range(FirstRow, lastrow).FormulaR1C1 = "=(c4-14)"
            Selection.AutoFill Destination:=ActiveCell.Range("A1:A" & lastrow)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=ActiveCell.Range("A1:A" & lastrow)
```

try

```
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=ActiveCell.Range("A1:A" & lastrow.Row)
```